# jquery - create recursive tree - Time-consuming

Tags: jquery, html, performance, time, tree

I need retrieve a json data source by ajax and then render it to html TREE.
**)I wrote my code in typescript.

In one sample 413 nodes exist that have 3 level on tree.

First I recognize parent children and call getLiNode for each.
Then for each parent i get children and do previous process for each and so on.
**)For binding json data to each node i used handlebasrsjs.

My problem is that generating tree nodes with this approach has very low performance and often take more than 2 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
static createParentNodes($tree: JQuery, $nodeContainer: JQuery, nodes: any, settings: any) {
    let $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    $ul.appendTo($nodeContainer);
    nodes.forEach(function (s: any, e: any) {
        gmTree.getLiNode($tree, $ul, s, settings);
    });
}
static getLiNode($tree: JQuery, $node: JQuery, data: any, settings: any) {
    let $li = $('<li class="treeLi" data-id="' + data.id + '"></li>');
    let $parent = $node.closest('li');
    let treeId = $tree.attr("id");
    $li.data("nodeData", data);
    if (settings != null) $li.data("parentId", settings.parentId);
    $li.data("parent", $parent);
    $li.data("objectData", data);

    let $liNode = $('<div class="tree-li-data"></div>');
    let $expander = $('<span class="hidden" data-role="tree-expander"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>');
    let checkboxId = 'chk_' + data.id;
    let $checkbox = $('<span class="hidden" data-role="tree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="' + checkboxId + '" class="chk-col-blue"/><label for="' + checkboxId + '"></label></span>');
    let $display = $('<span data-role="tree-display" id="' + treeId + "Dis" + data.id + '"></span>');
    $expander.appendTo($liNode);
    $checkbox.appendTo($liNode);
    $display.appendTo($liNode);
    $liNode.appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo($node);

    let finalData = data.data;
    if (finalData == undefined)
        finalData = data;
    let textTemplate: string = "";
    if (settings != null && settings.textTemplate != null)
        textTemplate = settings.textTemplate;

    if (textTemplate == undefined || textTemplate == "") {
        textTemplate = $tree.data("textTemplate");
    }
    var source = textTemplate;
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var result = template(finalData);
    $display.html(result);

    if (data.children.length > 0) {
        $expander.removeClass('hidden');

        gmTree.createParentNodes($tree, $li, data.children, { parentId: data.id });
    }
    else {
        $checkbox.removeClass('hidden');
    }
    $li.trigger(ON_NODE_CREATED, { data: finalData });

}
```

[Image of my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS5h5.png)

Comment: I think one approach would be not creating children elements immediately. You can create them after clicking on each parent item.

Comment: Thanks
But, I used lazy load approach.
Sometimes, I wanna create all in one time, if possible.